# react-native how do I show activityindicator while file uploading

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I want to have a loading spinner appear in the middle of the screen while the file is being uploaded.
The clicked file is loaded and appears in the file list as well.
I imported ActivityIndicator from 'react-native'.
When I wrote the code after  as a test, the loading spinner was well seen.
However, I wanted to make the spinner appear only the file is loaded. So, I wrote the code, but the loading spinner does not appear.

```
import {Text,View,ImageBackground,Image,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity,FlatList,Button,ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';

export default function FileUpload({route, navigation}) {

    
    const [multipleFile, setMF] = useState([])
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        }, 5000);
    }, [])

    const addEntry = (data) => {
        
       let newObj = {
            "id": randId(),
            "name" : data.filename,
            "text" : data.text,
        }
        console.log('Finish load');

        setMF([...multipleFile, newObj]);
        console.log(multipleFile)
    };
    const randId = () => {
        let id = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            id += String.fromCharCode(Math.trunc(Math.random()*85) + 48)
        }
        return id
    }
    const sendFile = () => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '',
            data: {
                "uri": ""
            }
        }).then((res) =>{
           addEntry(res.data)
           
        } 
        ).catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    );

    
                
return (
   <ImageBackground source={require('../images/bg2.png')} 
      style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
          
          <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync().then((res) => {
                    console.log(res)
                    if (res.type == 'success') { 

                        console.log('load start');  
                                             
                        if(isLoading){
                            return(
                                <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                    <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
                                </View>
                            );
                        }
                        sendFile()

                    } else {
                        console.log('you cancelled')
                    }
                })

                
            }} 
                  style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                  <Image source ={require('../images/cloud.png')}
                          style={styles.image}        
                  />
                    
                  <View style={styles.viewTextStyle}>
                      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{'Upload Files'} </Text>
                      <Text style={{fontSize:60, color:'white'}}> + </Text>                        
                      <Text style={styles.textStyle1}>{'Browse and select your file \n you want to upload'}</Text>
                  </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.listHeader}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 18}}> File List </Text>
      </View>
        <FlatList
            style={styles.scrollContainer}
            data={multipleFile}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}>
        </FlatList>
        {/* <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                    <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
                                </View> */}
          
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
        // console.log(multipleFile[0].name)
        navigation.navigate('Details Search', 
            multipleFile[0]
          )}}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Next</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
      
  </ImageBackground> 
);
}
```

Comment: pass your loading state into ActivityIndicator `animating` prop ```<ActivityIndicator size="large" animating={loading}/>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the default state to `false`

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

remove this `effect`

```
useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        }, 5000);
    }, [])
```

remove loading view from `DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync()`

```
if (res.type == 'success') {                                                                         
  sendFile() 
  } else {
      console.log('you cancelled')
  }
```

set `loading` true/false in sendFile()

```
const sendFile = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '',
            data: {
                "uri": ""
            }
        }).then((res) =>{
           setLoading(false)
           addEntry(res.data)
           
        } 
        ).catch((err) =>  setLoading(false));
    }
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    );
```

add `loading view` in main return

```
return (
....

if(isLoading){
                            return(
                                <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                    <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
                                </View>
                            );
                        }
....

)
```